# Iterator in C language

Tags: c

Has anyone tried providing support for Iterator in C.
I am not looking for exact C++ STL::Iterator but minimal support for some idea to start would be good point for me .

I am developing container library same like stl but with minimal support, So I need this kind of functionality in those container.

I am looking forward of defining certain sets of algorithms interfaces ( similar to STL ). For example sort , which will take begin and end iterator and should work with any container.

Comment: isn't an Iterator in C called a pointer?

Comment: @AShelly sort of, but usually iterators have some concept of whether or not there's another value, which pointers do not have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed to use LGPL code in your project have a look at GLib instead of re-inventing the wheel. GLib allows also to develop in a quite portable way at source code level.

Have a look at `g_list_first()` and `g_list_next()` which implement the functionality of an iterator on the list. There is even a g_list_foreach()`

http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html

Comment: Isn't glib LGPL, i.d. can't you (dynamically) link to it from non-GPL code?

Comment: @delnan, you're are fully right! And I always thought it was under GPL... LGPL is absolutely fine but then only dynamically linked.

Answer (score 20):

Pointers can serve this function.  `container.begin()` is easy, and `container.end()` doesn't take too much work.

Consider

```
Value array[N];
typedef Value* iterator;
iterator array_begin(Value a[]){ return &a[0];}
iterator array_end(Value a[], int n){ return &a[n];}
iterator array_next(iterator i) { return ++i;}

iterator it = array_begin(a);
iterator end = array_end(a,N);
for (;it < end; it=array_next(it))
{
    Value v = *it;
}
```

For other containers like lists, you can use NULL as end.  Same for trees, but the `next` function needs to maintain state.  (or the iterator is a pointer to a struct with state updated by calls to `next(it)`).

Comment: This basic skeleton is a great point to start for a simple iterator. But the `array_next` function should return `(i + 1)` or `++i`, since `i++` will just return `i` and not actually move to the next item.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at linked lists. A node includes a "next" pointer that one can use to iterate through the list, in a manner analogous to C++ iterators:

```
typedef struct Node {
    ...                                                                                                                                                           
    struct Node *next;                                                                                                                                                          
} Node;  

...

Node *iter, *firstNode, *nodeList; 

/* set firstNode and populate nodeList */

for (iter = firstNode; iter != NULL; iter = iter->next) {
    /* iterate through list */
}
```

It's not a C++ iterator, but hopefully this gives an idea of one way to approach this in C.

Comment: You're mixing stuff up. A linked list, like an array, is a data structure. OP is asking for an iterator - which can be used to iterate different data structures in a uniform way.

Comment: I'm just providing an analogy. There is no such thing available directly in C, so the analogy of a linked list is provided to show how such a thing might work.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a standardized way of *incrementing* the iterator. In C++, that's just the overloaded `operator++()`. Your container needs an associated function that returns a pointer to the next element. This incrementing function would need to be passed as a pointer to any generalized routine that can accept an iterator in your library.

For example, If I want to write a function that returns the **max** element from the container, I need not only the comparison function (the equivalent of `operator<()`), I need an iterator-incrementing function (the equivalent of `operator++()`).

So ensuring that I can accept a pointer to your incrementing function is the key requirement.

Comment: Why go to that level of complexity, chrisaycock?  The module that defines the iterator data structure would simply have an increment function that takes the address of the current iterator.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
typedef struct PWDict PWDict;
typedef struct PWDictIterator PWDictIterator;

typedef struct PWDictImplementation
{
    PWDict *(*create)(const struct PWDictImplementation *impl, size_t elements);
    void (*destroy)(PWDict *dict);

    unsigned int (*size)(const PWDict *dict);
    unsigned int (*sizeInBytes)(const PWDict *dict);

    int (*get)(const PWDict *dict, const char *key, char *output, size_t size);
    int (*set)(PWDict *dict, const char *key, const char *value);

    PWDictIterator *(*iteratorCreate)(const PWDict *dict);
    void (*iteratorBegin)(PWDictIterator *it);
    void (*iteratorEnd)(PWDictIterator *it);
    void (*iteratorDestroy)(PWDictIterator *it);

    const char *(*iteratorGetKey)(const PWDictIterator *it);
    const char *(*iteratorGetValue)(const PWDictIterator *it);
    int (*iteratorSetValue)(PWDictIterator *it, const char *value);
    void (*iteratorNext)(PWDictIterator *it);
}
PWDictImplementation;

struct PWDict
{
    PWDictImplementation *impl;
};

struct PWDictIterator
{
    PWDict *dict; /* get iterator implementation from the dict implementation */
};
```

PW is our project prefix.
We just needed a dictionary (string-string map) like container.

Answer (score 0):

I found one open source project which is STL implementation in C language.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tstl2cl/